# unable to display arabic characters using jdbc in eclipse maven project

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, oracle11g

I have a spring boot project that uses JDBC to query a database row.
The content of row is in Arabic character set **AR8MSWIN1256**.

When I run this as mvn clean package spring-boot:run the output prints only question mark.
I am using Oracle 11G and jdk 8. I already tried setting -Dfile.encoding, eclipse sts encoding to utf-8 or utf-16 but no luck.

Here is the code I have:

Example write query (prepared statement):

```
INSERT INTO <TABLE_NAME> VALUES (1,1,'ممرضة التشفير شفير شفير شف','R20');
```

Example read query

```
SELECT * FROM <TABLE_NAME> WHERE ID=?;
```

Code to print:

```
    ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();        
    String resultStrId = null;
    while (rs.next()) {
        resultStrId = rs.getString(1);
        System.out.println(resultStrId);
        System.out.println(rs.getString(2));
        break;
    }
    rs.close();
```

Output from program:

```
Success from preparedStatement prepare for version 19.6.0.0
????? ??????? ???? ???? ??
```

Expected output:

```
ممرضة التشفير شفير شفير شف
```

Note: I don't understand Arabic

Comment: Also i can see and view the value in Araic using sqldeveloper sqlplus in database.

Comment: Try adding file [orai18n.jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.oracle.ojdbc/orai18n/19.3.0.0) to your CLASSPATH.

Comment: Hi @Abra its already present 

  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
   <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
   <version>${jdbc.version}</version>
   <scope>compile</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>com.oracle.ojdbc</groupId>
      <artifactId>orai18n</artifactId>
      <version>19.3.0.0</version>
  </dependency>

Comment: probably not database related... have you tried `System.out.println("ممرضة التشفير شفير شفير شف")` ?

Comment: Thank's @user16320675 , nice suggestion added and observed a strange behaviour
Directly running the sop in eclipse works fine, when it is run as maven project it displays questions marks instead of characters

Comment: since its working fine when directly running in eclipse is it not the problem with maven?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245755/discussion-between-amit-mahajan-and-user16320675).

Comment: As i mentioned, I already set UTF-8 encoding
Not only in file.encoding but also in eclipse workspace settings

Comment: Thanks checking the chcp 65001 option